# javascript algorithim that I cant somehow get right

Tags: javascript

Ok this will be a mouthful.

So I'm relatively new to javascript and know some essential functions like if statements and repeat loops. I'm developing an algorithm to help you with PC parts. So for example it takes your budget and then assigns a reasonable price for each part from your budget and what you will use the PC for. Which you can select from an HTML CSS checkbox. So there are the values below:

Gamer means More Budget to GPU and maybe CPU
YT/Streamer/Musician means Less Gpu and More CPU and lots of RAM
Data Storage means Motherboard with lots of op and case with lots of drive mounts
3D/VE means Quite Fast GPU pretty good CPU lots of storage and RAM
Engineer means More reliable products
Programmer means Hefty CPU and lots of RAM

And I've written that into JS Which defines the variables for the youtubestreamer/gamer etc are for either y or n y being if its checked. If it is it adds the percent to CPUp GPUp (p being percent)

The issue is that the code assigns the values not based off the other ones. Like I need the values to be out of 100 and also include casep which is just the extra amount. I wrote some really weird code to try to balance it out:

```
   let val = 2000;
let Modeler3dvideoeditor = 'y';
let dataStorage = 'n';
let engineer = 'n';
let gamer = 'y';
let programmer = 'y';
let youtubestreamer = 'y';
let CPUp = 20;
let GPUp = 15;
let RAMp = 15;
let Motherboardp = 15;
let psuP = 10;
let Storagep = 10;
let casep = 10;
let rem = 0;
calculateIf();



function calculateIf() {
    if (engineer === 'y') {
        GPUp += 15;
        Motherboardp -= 2.5;
    }
    if (dataStorage === 'y') {
        CPUp -= 5;
        GPUp -= 5;
        Motherboardp += 10;
        psuP += 5;
        casep += 10;
    }
    if (Modeler3dvideoeditor === 'y') {
        CPUp += 15;
        GPUp += 10;
        RAMp += 10;
        Storagep += 5;
    }
    if (programmer === 'y') {
        CPUp += 15;
        GPUp += 5;
        RAMp += 15;
        Storagep += 5;
    }
    if (youtubestreamer === 'y') {
        CPUp += 15;
        GPUp += 10;
        RAMp += 15;
        Storagep += 5;
    }
    if (gamer === 'y') {
        CPUp -= 5;
        GPUp += 10;
        RAMp += 5;
        Storagep += 5;
    }
    if (CPUp > 45) {
        CPUp -= 15;
    }
    if (GPUp > 40) {
        GPUp -= 15;
    }
    if (Motherboardp < 15) {
        Motherboardp += 10;
    }
    if (RAMp > 30) {
        RAMp -= 40;

    }
    CPUp -= 6;
    GPUp -= 6;
    casep = 100 - CPUp - GPUp - RAMp - psuP - Storagep;

    if (casep < 0) {
        const divide = ((casep * -1 + 15) / 7);
        CPUp = CPUp - divide;
        GPUp = GPUp - divide;
        Motherboardp = Motherboardp - divide;
        RAMp = RAMp - divide;
        psuP = psuP - divide;
        Storagep = Storagep - divide;
        casep = casep + (casep * -1) + 15;
    }
    if (Storagep < 0) {
        const divide = ((Storagep * -1 + 15) / 7);
        CPUp = CPUp - divide;
        GPUp = GPUp - divide;
        Motherboardp = Motherboardp - divide;
        RAMp = RAMp - divide;
        psuP = psuP - divide;
        casep = casep - divide;
        Storagep = 100 - CPUp - GPUp - RAMp - psuP - casep;
    }
    Storagep -= 12.5;
    if (psuP < 0) {
        const divide = ((psuP * -1 + 15) / 7);
        CPUp = CPUp - divide;
        GPUp = GPUp - divide;
        Motherboardp = Motherboardp - divide;
        RAMp = RAMp - (RAMp / divide);
        Storagep = Storagep - divide;
        casep = casep - divide;
        psuP = 100 - CPUp - GPUp - RAMp - psuP - casep;
    }
    rem = 100 - CPUp - GPUp - RAMp - psuP - Storagep - casep;
    psuP = psuP + rem / 2;
    CPUp = CPUp + rem / 4;
    GPUp = GPUp + rem / 4;
    rem = rem - rem;
}

console.log(CPUp);
console.log(GPUp);
console.log(Motherboardp);
console.log(RAMp);
console.log(psuP);
console.log(Storagep);
console.log(casep);
console.log(rem);
```

And it really didn't do anything.

Honestly, you don't have to help because this is a really dumb topic and I've left this on hold for almost 2 weeks because I've been unable to think of a solution.

Thank you if you do decide to help.

Comment: Your numbers don't add up. And I don't mean at the end, I mean basically nowhere in your code. You start off with a total of just `95%`. What about the remaining `5%`? And if I check of `Modeler3dvideoeditor`, `programmer` and `youtubestreamer` your percentages go up by `125%` to a total of `220%`. That's more than **twice the budget**. Your problem is that you have no algorithm, not even a concept how this should work. You're just throwing random numbers around and wonder that they don't add up. Sorry if that's harsh, but as it is, I don't know how we could help.

Comment: No it's not harsh, thats the probem I'm experiencing, I've been thinking that I could try to have it so it comes out to 100% no matter what but I have no idea how to develop an algorithm. I guess its back to Mozilla docs with me. Thank you